# How to cancel a synchronized method of a library?

Tags: android, asynchronous, handler, modbus

In an android project of mine I'm using the jamod library for Modbus communication and it works alright. Except when the network connection isn't available then my asynchronous task will be stuck on `transaction.execute` for seconds. I would like to cancel it after a given timeout. I tried to implement a handler for this to cancel the asynchronous task:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

      if (task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING
          || task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
        task.cancel(true);
      }
    }
  }, WRITE_TASK_TIMOUT);
```

But this approach won't work. I looked into the library and saw that the `ModbusTCPTransaction.execute()` method uses `synchronized()`.

Does this mean i have no chance to cancel this method after x seconds?

Comment: Please, post more info about your code, it's not enough to detect the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Android class [Future](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). It has method to set the timeout period of the thread execution.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task());
future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


static class Task implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        //ModbusTCPTransaction.execute()
        return null;
  }
}
```